# Convert DatePicker Value to String in windows store app

Tags: c#, datepicker, windows-store-apps

I have converted date picker values to string like this

```
BookingDate = date.Date.ToString();
```

but its gives value like this
`18-Aug-14 3:21:01 PM -07:00` . I only want in this format `18/8/14` , How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format your `DateTime` like;

```
date.Date.ToString(@"dd\/M\/yy");
```

or

```
date.Date.ToString("dd'/'M'/'yy");
```

And I don't believe [`DateTime.Date` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) returns `PM -07:00` as an hour because from documentation;

> A new object with the same date as this instance, and the time value
>   **set to 12:00:00 midnight (00:00:00)**.